# Is it possible to wire up a custom UIImagePickerController class with a viewController on the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I want this class to wire up with a storyboard scene. The current result is that my storyboard view controller displays my saved photos album. i want to customise this class so it displays the camera. Is there a way to do this here without having to create a UIViewController class and create and display a UIImagePickerController within that? Reason being is I am using a UIPageController so dont want to have to call a modal imagepickervc.

```
class CameraViewController: UIImagePickerController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [UIImagePickerController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/)

> IMPORTANT
>
> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
>   class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.

Comment: Ahhh really I'm stuffed then!